# addeventlistener to indexed element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of elements. However, the length of this list varies between trials. For example, sometimes there are 6 elements and sometimes there are 8. The exact number is detailed in an external metadata.

To display this variable list, I've written:

```
var html = '';
html += '<div id="button' + ind + '" class="buttons">';
html += '<p>' + name + '</p></div>';
display_element.innerHTML = html;
```

If I were to 'inspect' the elements in my browser, they would appear to have `ID`s of `button0.buttons`, `button1.buttons`, etc.

Now I am trying to attach event listeners to each element but my code is not working so far. Different forms of broken code below:

```
document.getElementById("button' + ind + '").addEventListener("click", foo);
$("#button' + ind + '").click(foo);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", foo);
$("#button").click(foo);
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You already assigned them a class="buttons". Why not use $(".buttons") to add your event listner too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrong at `concat` string update it as

```
document.getElementById("button" + ind).addEventListener("click", foo);
```

```js
var html = '';
var ind = 1;
var display_element = document.getElementById("test");
html += '<div id="button' + ind + '" class="buttons">';
html += '<p>' + name + '</p></div>';
display_element.innerHTML = html;


document.getElementById("button" + ind).addEventListener("click", foo);

function foo(){
alert('click');
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "document.getElementsByClassName" get all botton elements then foreach to add click function.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('buttons').map( element => { element.addEventListener("click", foo) })
```

Comment: or in jQuery... $(".buttons").on("click",function(event) {...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why neither of those uses of `document.getElementById()` are working for you, you are mixing your quotes incorrectly. `"button' + ind '"` evaluates to exactly that, rather than evaluating to `"button0"`, `"button1"`, etc. To make your code more readable, and to avoid similar quote mixing issues, I would recommend looking into template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

With modern JS if you want to execute the same function you won't require to add an id to each button.
Just use the class added to the buttons like this:

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('.buttons').forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener('click',foo);
    });
```

Then use the event parameter in that function to get the target node & execute whatever you want. You can also add data attributes in those buttons to use while executing that function.